# Flutter (IOS) In-app-purchase local receipt

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

In flutter, I am using the flutter developed In-app-purchases package, how do I access the receipt data (IOS) from the transaction to send to my server? I'm attempting to do receipt validation, but so far cannot seem to find the correct data. This is for a subscription if that makes a difference. Thank you!

Comment: i also face the same problem but i found the solution. the solution is to Make Api call to Appstore SandBox: “https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt” iTunes Store : “https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt” The below of the Link also help you https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if the previous answer is correct. As of right now (Dec 2022), it should be `purchaseDetails.verificationData.serverVerificationData` **for both iOS and Android**.

On Android the `localVerificationData` contains decoded copy of that receipt, not the tokenized version, so the correct field to use for both is the `serverVerificationData`.

Here's [the detailed instruction](https://fortreef.com/flutter-in-app-purchase-validation-with-net-6/) on validation of Flutter in-app purchases using netcore 6 Web API for both iOS and Android.

Answer (score 1):

Receipt verification data can be retrieved from `purchaseDetails.verificationData.localVerificationData`.

This is already a base64 encoded string and can be used in the json format to query Apple's server at https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt (url for Sandbox testing only).

Comment: from where can i call your code "purchaseDetails.verificationData.localVerificationData". Which package  is use for this?